# How to use the output of GetMetaData activity in copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to copy file from a folder to Azure BLOB Storage using copy activity and this copy activity should run only when the file exists in the specific folder. Im using GETMETADATA Activity to see if the file exists, but where i need to configure this output so that copy activity gets triggered when the file exists. I will use @activity(GetMetadata1).exists. But where i need to check this value is true in Copy activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [dynamic content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#sample-output):`@{activity('MyGetMetadataActivity').output.exists}` in [If-Condition Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity).

[image]

Output:

[image]